# Robot Framework / RIDE - Arguments with spaces

Tags: python, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I have to run several test cases on different configurations. When I run a test case from the command line I want to pass the name of the configuration as a variable.

I use something like: --variable CONFIG:xxx

This is working fine. Now I have configurations with spaces in between, and there is no way for me to change the names, so I have to deal with the spaces. So when I use the following line: --variable CONFIG:xxx bbb aaa

Its not working, because of the spaces, when I do --variable CONFIG:xxxbbbaaa it is accepted as a proper value, but its not the actual name of the configuration so its not working.

How can I pass the value of a variable that contains spaces to Robot?

Thanks.

Comment: Try putting quotes around the value. Or escape the space with a `\`.

Comment: The quotes are not working, the moment I enter a space in RIDE the bar turns red and I cant run it.

Comment: So if I want to escape the space I need to put it like: —variabele CONFIG: xxx.bbb.aaa? Dont think it will work but will give it a try.

Comment: Sorry, my comment didn't come out correctly. There was supposed to be a backslash between the backticks...but that seems to have escaped the backticks. So...my suggestion is to escape a space with a backslash

Comment: Will try that too 

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in robot, or are you specifically asking about RIDE? From the command line you can use quotes.

Comment: I want to know how to do it in RIDE.